# Recording and replaying MySQL database load

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm debugging a problem with slow queries in a MySQL server. Queries normally complete in 100-400 millisecs but sometimes rocket to 10's or 100's of seconds.

The queries are generated by an application over which I have no control, and there are multiple databases (one for each customer). The slow queries seem to appear randomly, and neither RAM, disk or CPU is loaded when the slow queries are logged. When I run the queries manually, they run fine (as in millisecs), which makes me suspect locking issues in combination with other read and write queries. The queries itself are horrible (unable to use the index in either the WHERE or ORDER BY clause) but the largest tables are relatively small (up to 200.000 rows), and there are almost no JOINs. When I profile the queries, most time is spent sorting the result (in the case where the query runs fine).

I'm unable to reproduce the extreme slowness in a test environment, and my best idea right now is to stop the production MySQL server, create a copy of the databases, enable full query logging and starting the server again. This way I should be able to replay the load and reproduce the problem. But the general query log seems to only record the query, not the target database for the query. Do I have any other record / replay options for MySQL?

Comment: Have you run any of the MySQL benchmarking tools to makes sure it's not the hardware or drive configuration that's causing problems? Sometimes a misconfigured RAID array can completely destroy any performance, or you could be running inside of a badly configured VM.

Comment: I can't use the synthetic benchmarks because the issue only appears on this specific workload. I'm on a physical 8-core Xeon machine with 16GB RAM doing nothing else. I even tried moving MySQL data files to a tmpfs filesystem with no improvement.

Comment: I found the tool pt-log-player from Percona which should be able to replay from the General Log File.

Comment: I've installed JetProfiler which captured this picture of thread states: http://i45.tinypic.com/p3nes.png. It looks like there's a thread in the "writing to net" state for a full minute! It also looks like this thread is holding a table lock on a table which a new connection is waiting for. What would put a thread sending 80.000 rows in that state for so long (there's full 100MBit between server and client), and why is the table lock not released before sending? These are MyISAM tables - maybe InnoDB with row-level locking would help?

Comment: I found the cause of the behavior. When the slow queries happen, one thread is bombarding the table with updates and selects while another thread is waiting to access the table. So it's a locking issue. The waiting thread is in the "writing to net" state instead of the "waiting for table lock" state which does seem odd.

Comment: If you're using InnoDB you can always inspect what's going on with `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`, though trying to figure out exactly what's going on in that can be like finding a needle in a haystack.

Comment: My attempt with pt-log-player failed. Apparently, the locking issue is too sensitive to timing. Currently, I'm testing whether "sql_buffer_result=1" has any measurable effect on the "writing to net" state. I read somewhere that this state still blocks the table and that threads can stay in this state if the client is consuming rows in the result set very slowly (either deliberately or because of slow network).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally nailed the problem. The application is doing something like this:

```
cursor = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM `LargeTable`")
while cursor.has_more_rows():
  cursor.fetchrow()
  do_something_that_takes_a_while()
cursor.close()
```

It's fetching and processing the result set, 1 row at a time. If the loop takes 100 seconds to complete, then the table is locked on the server for 100 seconds.

Changing this setting on the MySQL server:

```
set global SQL_BUFFER_RESULT=ON;
```

made the slow queries disappear instantly, because result sets are now pushed to a temp table so the table lock can be removed, regardless of how slowly the application consumes the result set. The setting brings in a host of other performance problems, but fortunately the server is dimensioned to handle these problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the slow query log: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html

Just set the threshold to a very small value (hopefully you're running mysql > 5.1 )

Otherwise you can use tcpdump:
http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/11/07/poor-mans-query-logging/

and of course if you use that, you may want to look at the percona toolkit's pt-query-digest to process the tcpdump output: http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-query-digest.html

For future reference, you may want to set up query and server monitoring:
https://github.com/box/Anemometer/wiki
and 
https://github.com/box/RainGauge/wiki/What-is-Rain-Gauge%3F

Comment: I'm not sure the slow query log adds any insight which the OP doesn't already get from the general query log; and I guess tcpdump is only useful if connecting over TCP without SSL (what happens if using UNIX sockets?).

Comment: The [general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html) can log everything if you want.

Comment: @eggyal yes it's not clear exactly what the user's environment and requirements are.  I threw out some options.  Various tools exist that make working with the slow query log convenient, and the added performance info might even help show his problem.  His performance problem is quite complex and this isn't the approach I would take to  solve it, but it would be quite a long explanation to tell him everything about how to troubleshoot server performance issues.

Comment: I'm on MySQL 5.5. All connections are via TCP, so I could try tcpdump or setting the slow query log threshold to 0. It's not clear to me that the General Query Log actually logs the target database of a query.

Answer (score 0):

Percona is working on a new tool called Playback which does exactly what you want:
http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/04/09/percona-playback-0-6-for-mysql-now-available/